# Making My Sidebar Dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, sidebar

I've having a lot of trouble finding a plugin that I could use to make my sidebar drop down as an animation. It is already functional but it would put the icing on the cake (Kingdom Hearts fans). Here's the CSS, JS, and HTML used to make the sidebar. I'm still learning JS so if anyone could help me figure it out that would be great!

```
$(function () {
    $(".sidebar-hidden, #menu-close").click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(".sidebar-hidden").toggle();
      $(".sidebar").toggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
      if ($(".sidebar").is(":visible")) {
        $(".sidebar-hidden").toggle();
        $(".sidebar").toggle();
      }
    });
    $(".sidebar").click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
  });


.sidebar-hidden {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #86c7ff;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: #86c7ff;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  min-width: 105px;
  &:hover {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    li {
      padding: 4px;
      border-top: dotted 1px;
      &:first-child {
        border-top: none;
      }
      a {
        text-indent: 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        -o-transition:.5s;
        -ms-transition:.5s;
        -moz-transition:.5s;
        -webkit-transition:.5s;
        transition:.5s;
        display: block;
        &:hover {
          color: white;
          font-size: 17px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

<div class="sidebar-hidden">
  <i style="font-size: 18px" class="icon-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
<div class="sidebar" style="display: none;">
  <p id="menu-close" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">Tools&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon-arrow-left"></i></p>
  <ul>
    <li class="s-b-border"><a href="#"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> Syncro </a></li>
    <li class="s-b-border"><a id="Tool-BoM" href="#"><i class="icon-file"></i> BoM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-hdd"></i> Override&nbsp;</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*Note: Anything that has BoM in it is relating to another file in my project so just ignore it.

Comment: Have you looked at `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`?

Comment: No I haven't. I'll look into that right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) takes `duration` as an argument, which you can specify to add an animating effect to your sidebar.

in your case, replace `.toggle()` with,

```
.toggle("slow") //or number of milliseconds of the animation duration
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/n8Mjh/)

Comment: This was exactly what i needed. Simple, easy, perfect.

Comment: @HandofLogi great :) glad I could help, please upvote and accept the answer by hitting the arrow mark :D cheers

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like if someone clicks anywhere on the page it is going to toggle the sidebar.  I would go with what Andrew said and use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`